# MassTransit Receive by sessionId

Tags: azureservicebus, masstransit

If I send messages into a session-enabled queue and each message has a sessionID, can I configure a consumer to receive messages only with sessionID = X.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can filter subscriptions on things like `SessionId`, or even `PartitionKey` for that matter.

You can only create subscription filters on message properties, which are typically passed through as headers by MassTransit. Those end up as properties on the message, with which the SqlFilter style of subscription filter can be used.

Filter can be created on subscription endpoints:

```cs
configurator.SubscriptionEndpoint<ClientUpdated>("client-update-27", x =>
{
    x.Rule = new CreateRuleOptions("Only27", new SqlRuleFilter("ClientId = 27"));
    // ...
});
```

Or on receive endpoints with explicit subscriptions:

```cs
x.ReceiveEndpoint("queue-name", e =>
{
    e.Subscribe<MessageA>("subscription-name", 
    s => s.Filter = new SqlRuleFilter("ClientId = 27"));
});
```